# How to query all subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, tags, many-to-many, nosql

I'm beginning with MongoDb and nodejs (using mongoose).

I have a collection of **Stories**, each of them can have one or more **Tags**, it's something like that:

```
{
    title: "The red fox",
    content: "The red fox jumps away...",
    tags: [
        {
            tagname: "fairytale",
            user: "pippo"
        },
        {
            tagname: "funny",
            user: "pluto"
        },
        {
            tagname: "fox",
            user: "paperino"
        }
    ]
},

... other stories
```

Now I want to make a **tag cloud**.

It means querying Stories for all tags.

In a relational world (e.g. MySQL) I would have a Stories table, a Tags table and a Stories_Tags table (many-to-many). Then I'd query on the tags table or something like that.

Is there a way to do so? (I'm sure yes)

If yes, is it a good practice? Or does it break the nosql paradigm?

Can you imagine a better way for my schema design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an MR to accomplish this. In an MR you would simply pick out the tags and project them:

```
var map = function(){
     for(var i=0;i<this.tags.length;i++){
         emit(this.tags[i].tagname, {count: 1});
     }
}
```

And then your reduce would run through the emitted documents basically summing up the amount of times that tag was seen.

If you upgrade to the lastest unstable 2.2 you can also use the aggregation framework. You would use the $project and $sum piplines of the aggregation framework to project the tags out of each post and then summing them up to create a score based tag cloud allowing you size the text of each tag based upon the summing.

> If yes, is it a good practice? Or does it break the nosql paradigm?

This is a pretty standard problem in MongoDB and one you won't get away from. With the reusable structure comes the inevitable need to do some complex querying over it. Fortunately in 2.2 there is the aggregationm framework to save.

As to whether this is a good or bad approach, it is a pretty standard one as such it is neither good or bad.

As to making the structure better, you could pre-aggregate unique tags with their count to a separate collection. This would make it easier to build your tag cloud in realtime.

Pre-aggregation is a form of creating the other collection you would normally get from an MR without the need to use MRs or the aggregation framework. It is normally event based upon your app, so when a user create a post or retags a post it will trigger a pre-aggregation event to a collection of "tag_count" which looks like:

```
{
    _id: {},
    tagname: "",
    count: 1
}
```

When the event is triggered your app will loop through the tags on the post basically doing $inc upserts like so:

```
db.tag_count.update({tagname: 'whoop'}, {$inc: {count: 1}}, true);
```

And so you will now have a collection of tags with their count throughout your blog. From there you go the same route as the MR did and just query this collection getting out your data. You would of course need to handle deletion and update events but you get the general idea.

Comment: so, if I understand now, that "counting tags" tutorial in mongodb docs creates another collection "tags" which contains the result of the calculations? And each time I want to "refresh" the tag cloud I have to re-execute the MR? I can't understand what you mean for "pre-aggregate unique tags".... If you help me with that, the right answer is yours :)

Comment: @FabioB. Ok added a little explanation

Comment: thank you very much, since you're so kind I complete with: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html What do you think? It seems another possible solution: a "Stories" and a "Tags" Schema. Then Stories holds an array of ObjectIds (tags) and when I want all my tags I simply query the "Tags" collection. So?

Comment: @FabioB. That could work though you will need to ensure distinction within your tags collection, you could use the upsert I showed in my answer to ensure uniqueness

Comment: isn't there a way to create a unique field in a mongodb document?

Comment: IN ADDITION: so do you think that this answer is not scalable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154516/query-embedded-documents/12154974#12154974

Comment: @FabioB. Indeed, `ensureIndex({ 'tagname': 1 }, {unique: 1})` but I have found that it is normally better to ensure uniqueness through atomic updates due to future expansion on most functionality.

Comment: @FabioB. I am surprised Stennie gave that answer, distinct is notoriously slow, I mean it does work but as to whether it would be done within a fast enough period of time on a large collection...hmmm `:\` results haven't been promising.

Comment: @FabioB. Though I guess it depends on how many users you have, if you have a small number of users then distinct might be fast enough.

Comment: @Sammaye: `distinct` has its uses, and "slow" depends on what you're doing and how often. The original question referenced had no mention of number of documents, just the attempt to do a distinct with a `find()`. The distinct function can use an index but still has to check all the matching keys for the criteria given. A more optimal data model could avoid the need for aggregates like distinct or count if those were common use cases. I think "notoriously slow" is more likely "notoriously misunderstood". Inspecting a lot of keys (or worse, documents!) is always going to be slower than a few.

Comment: You should check out Aggregate Framework released in 2.2. Take a look at Asya Kamsky answer. It's the right way to do it.

Comment: @DenisPshenov When this was written v2.2 of mongo (which the framework was released in) was not released to the public community as a stable product as such the aggregation framework was for future reference, since we cannot recommend something for production envo if it only exists in dev. Also pre-aggregation and MR are both valid as the aggregation framework here due to performance over extremely large data sets and return methods, also pre-aggregation is 1000x times faster than the framework so that answer isn't completely the "right" answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you do this using the aggregation framework (you need to use just released 2.2).

```
db.stories.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$unwind" : "$tags"
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$tags.tagname",
            "total" : {
                "$sum" : 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "total" : -1
        }
    }
])
```

Your result will look like this:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "fairytale",
            "total" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : "funny",
            "total" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "silly",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "fox",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: This is much faster than map reduce and in my opinion easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Mongo

The best "Schema" for your data will something like this.

You create a collection called stories, each story will be a document in this collection.
You can then easily query your data with something like.

```
db.stories.find({ "tags.tagname": "fairytale"}); // will find all documents that have fairytale as a tagname.
```

**UPDATE**

```
db.stories.find({ "tags.tagname": { $exists : true }}); // will find all documents that have a tagname.
```

Notice the dot notation in the find query, that's how you reach into arrays/objects in mongo.

Comment: good post... but you didn't get the point at all! I don't want to get a single story by tag. I want to get ALL TAGS (all tagnames).

Comment: Ok I have updated to find all documents with a tagname rather then specifying an actual tagname.

Comment: Uhm.... You make me have serious doubts about my english :) I meant only tags. Is it necessary to get all documents with tags?  And then what? How can I "SELECT DISTINCT tagname" ?

Comment: You can do this to not retrieve the title and content from the the stories documents:
`db.stories.find({ "tags.tagname": { $exists : true }, {"title": 0, content: 0 }})`
But you'll need to count the number of stories which have those tags.
You can do a function called mapped-reduce if you follow this tutorial:
http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/

Comment: @GianPaJ that tutorial is nice and simple but... it ends creating another collection with all tags... I simply want to have one query extracting all tags, then I will loop, count and distinct them. Is it so strange?

Comment: @FabioB. No however the answer given above will not work, you will be required to iterate and count the tags yourself which will result in code that will be slow and unscalable for large records. The aggregation framework in 2.2, as I said, solves this but the query above most definitely will not.

Comment: If this tag cloud is going to be displayed on the homepage for example where is going to receive a lot of traffic, it would be better to store this counts in another collection.
And every time a Storie is added do a `$inc` (increase) of those counters and or add a new tag

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are different ways. And I think there is no difference between your solution and [this one](https://github.com/chebyte/mongoid-simple-tags/blob/master/lib/mongoid-simple-tags.rb).

And also you can copy&paste its map_reduce method to output tag-count hash.

Comment: I cannot understand it (python). Can you briefly explain in the answer please?