# Query embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm going to create a schema like this:

```
[
    {
        username: "fabio",
        password: "xxx",
        roles: [
            {
                rolename: "administrator",
                isVip: true
            },
            {
                rolename: "manager",
                isVip: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        username: "marco",
        password: "yyy",
        roles: [
            {
                rolename: "manager",
                isVip: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        username: "pippo",
        password: "...",
        roles: [
            {
                rolename: "monkey",
                isVip: false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want to list all roles available in my app, starting from the users collection.

I think about a `SELECT DISTINCT rolename FROM ...` SQL statement.

**I'd like to get a result like `{"administrator","manager","monkey"}`** .

1. Is it possible?
2. **What query may I execute?** I tought about:

   db.users.find({ "roles.rolename": { $exists : true }});

   But that will find all users, not all roles.
3. Is it good? Or is it better creating another collection "roles" and keep an array of ObjectIds?
4. I am using Mongoose (mongodb for nodejs) so my query has to be ready for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [distinct()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) command to find the unique values:

```
> db.users.distinct('roles.rolename')
[ "administrator", "manager", "monkey" ]
```

Comment: is it efficient with billions of documents Users and Roles? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139334/how-to-query-all-subdocuments

Comment: If you have *billions* of users and roles you would approach your data model differently. At best, distinct is going to scan an index across all the documents provided as query criteria .. which can be fine if the index fits in memory. If you don't have an index, distinct would have to scan matching documents instead). It depends how often you actually need to find distinct roles, but you could also limit the query (eg. find new roles by date). An alternative data model would be to save distinct role names in their own collection (perhaps keyed by role name, or with a unique index on same).